# Кортеж и множество

Tags: python

```
import math
import itertools

n = 3
k = 0
x = []

for i in range(0, n+1):
        x.append(set([i]))

for i in range(0, n-1):
    temp = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), n-i))
    x.append(set(temp))

print(x)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {(1, 2, 3)}, {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}]
```

Хотелось бы получить так:

```
[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}]
```

Кортежи, скорее всего, получаются из-за `itertools.combinations`. Есть какие-то способы от них избавиться и перевести их в `set()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(0, n-1):
    for c in itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), n-i):
        x.append(set(c))
```